# What is best way to store 1 to N number in List in java?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I want to store the integers from 1 to N number in a List. Which is best way to store numbers in List considering time for executing iteration?

Actually i have string csv which have N numbers and i want to store it in List. i have tried with Arrays.AsList method after split csv. But it is taking much time.

Comment: Hello, which ways did you try?  Plain `for` loop, `IntStream` generate, range, iterate operations?

Comment: I have only tried Arrays.AsList method after spit csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`IntStream.rangeClosed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#rangeClosed-int-int-).

```
final List<Integer> numbers = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, N).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, N)` is better than `IntStream.range(1, N + 1)`. That method exists specifically for uses like this.

Comment: @Andreas Good suggestion.